# packaging .so libraries in a leiningen project

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I have got an `.so` file that needs to be on the class path in order for my program to work. what is the best way of packaging it in a leiningen project?

---

#### update

it worked really well... see https://github.com/zcaudate/sigar-native-deps for another example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

put them under a directory called native in your lein project as described here.

http://nakkaya.com/2010/04/05/managing-native-dependencies-with-leiningen/

Comment: in the article... there is a quote "First we need to package native libs according to the spec" do you know where that is?